# How to automatically close fancybox/lightbox/... popup after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, fancybox, lightbox

I have a test website (index.html) that opens a popup (popup.html) and closes it after three seconds. Here's the head of index.html:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function popup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=70,width=300');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Here's the body of index.html:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return popup('popup.html')">Open in pop-up</a>
```

Here's the head of popup.html:

```
<script>
    var howLong = 3000;
    t = null;
    function closeMe(){
        t = setTimeout("self.close()",howLong);
    }
</script>
```

Here's the body of popup.html:

```
<body onLoad="closeMe();self.focus()">
<p>Closing in 3 seconds</p>
</body>
```

**I'd like to show that popup using linghtbox/fancybox/whatever... and again close it after 3 seconds.** How can I do that? I tried all sorts of things and nothing worked. What's the easiest way to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fancybox and other lightboxes have a callback function that is called on open, and a public method to close it, have you tried triggering the close method inside the callback function (with timeout)?

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://fancybox.net/api). $.fancybox.close(); with setTimeout should be enough for you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Fancybox (either [version 1.3.x](http://fancybox.net/) or [version 2.x](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)) to open your external `html` document and close it after some seconds.

For fancybox **v1.3.x**, your html should look like:

```
<a href="page.html" class="fancybox">open fancybox and close it automatically after 3 seconds</a>
```

and the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  'width': 640, // or whatever
  'height': 320,
  'type': 'iframe',
  'onComplete': function(){
    setTimeout( function() {$.fancybox.close(); },3000); // 3000 = 3 secs
  }
 });
}); // ready
```

For fancybox **v2.x**, the html (notice the `class`):

```
<a href="page.html" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">open fancybox and close it automatically after 3 seconds</a>
```

and the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  width: 640, // or whatever
  height: 320,
  afterLoad: function(){
   setTimeout( function() {$.fancybox.close(); },3000); // 3000 = 3 secs
  }
 });
}); // ready
```

Comment: Any solution for fancybox4, the solutions above does not work .

Answer (score 1):

onComplete or afterLoad is not working for me, so I have added below code on parent page

```
window.closeFancyBox = function () {
        $.fancybox.close();
};
```

and from popup page I am calling below code

`$(window).load(function(){
        setTimeout( function() {window.parent.closeFancyBox(); },3000); // 3000 = 3 secs
});`

Answer (score 0):

create a function to close all fancybox afterload and set timeout for that function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   closefancybox();
});

function closefancybox() {
    $.fancybox({
        afterLoad: function () {$.fancybox.close();}
    });
    setTimeout(function () { closefancybox(); }, <time_inter>);
}
```